# Can I put a blacklight lamp into my softbox?

Tags: studio-lighting, uv

I have a softbox with an E27 bulb holder. Will it take a Blacklight lamp?

Comment: I have never seeing a case where you need a difused blacklight source, becouse all the reflective materials I have seeing are matt. This is an interesting question. But I m not sure if the light will be gone passing thru the softbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a wide variety of "black light" bulbs sold which will fit in an E27 socket. For your particular holder you need to determine the correct voltage/wattage range for which it is rated and find a bulb that falls within that range. If the holder also has any type of shade or shielding around the E27 socket you must also determine if a potential bulb will fit in the opening. Further, you need to determine what type of black light will work best for the photographs you desire to make. Then is is pretty much the simple task of using a search engine to find what you need.

Without more specific information regarding the exact bulb holder you wish to use it is not possible to answer your question more specifically.
Please note that for all practical purposes the standard bulb holder in the U.S., the E26, and the standard bulb holder in Europe, the E27, are interchangeable as the sizes are so close to one another. Bulbs that fit either one will usually fit the other as well.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear if you're trying to photograph per fluorescence, or some mixture of fluorescent and "white" light. In general fluorescence is weak so it won't take much white light to overwhelm the fluorescence.

Second the typical incandescent black light bulb doesn't put out too much UV radiation. You very well might need something stronger.

A fluorescent bulb may give you fits if it cycles at 60hz and you are using a shutter speed in that range or faster. Your eye can't see a 60hz flash, but a camera surely can.

There is both short and long wave UV. Most black lights create long wave UV, but most minerals fluoresce with short wave UV. So which type of UV light to use depends on what you're photographing.

UV lights with low visible light output have filters, which are really designed to pass UV and block visible light. The filter is much more expensive than the UV bulb itself. The black light bulbs with the glass bulb acting as the filter emit a relatively large amount of blue light.